# Hibernate ConstraintViolationException getConstraintName

Tags: hibernate

```
mysql> alter table metakey add constraint Name unique(name);
mysql> desc  metakey;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45)         | NO   | UNI |         |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


@Entity
@Table(name = "metakey",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="Name",columnNames={"name"})})
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class MetaKey implements Serializable{
    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @Column private String name;
}


sess.save(obj);
 ..
}catch(ConstraintViolationException cve){
  log.error(cve.getMessage());
  log.info("Constraint name:"+cve.getConstraintName());
}
```

I get these in log - cve.getConstraintName() returns null

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Duplicate entry 'Unit' for key 'Name'

could not insert: [com.comp.MetaKey]
Constraint name:null
```

Is there any way to find the constraint name?

Server version: 5.1.56
Hibernate version:3.6

Comment: Same problem using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc says :

> Returns the name of the violated
>   constraint, if known.
>
> ```
> Returns:
>     The name of the violated constraint, or null if not known.
> ```

So I guess the MySQL driver doesn't give access to the violated constraint name in the SQLException it generated, or Hibernate doesn't know how to get it from the SQLException.

Look at the details of the SQLException using a debugger, and see if it can be extracted from somewhere. If it can, then try extending the dialect in order to extract the constraint name.

Comment: cve.getCause().getMessage() returns "Duplicate entry 'Unit' for key 'Name'" where 'Name' is the constraint name

Answer (score 0):

Please check out me answering almost the same question: [Hibernate: constraintName is null in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118227/hibernate-constraintname-is-null-in-mysql/14498717#14498717)

Hope this helps, Alex.