# catching ConstraintViolationException from jpa gives constraint name null value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I use jpa and hibernate to persist my data.My model is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"username"}, name="username"))
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "user_role", nullable = false)
    private UserRole userRole;
}
```

I am catching the ConstraintViolationException to catch if a user is violating a unique value. But when I try to access the constraintName using ConstraintViolationException.getConstraintName() gives me null value. How can I know which column violated the constraint so to warn the user?

Answer (score 0):

try: `cve.getCause().getMessage()`

Comment: It gives Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'username'. So I need to extract the value and key. This comes from the `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. Can I be sure that this would always be the case? Isn't there a more generic way? What if more than one constraints get violated? There must be a more generic (automated) way.

Comment: I have found similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118227/hibernate-constraintname-is-null-in-mysql/14498717#14498717